Bound for expected value under Wasserstein metric
I'm reading a paper and the following result is presented:
$$ (\mathbb{E}_{F}[\|\mathbf{X}\|^k])^{1/k} \leq (\mathbb{E}_{F_{0}}[\|\mathbf{X}\|^k])^{1/k} + \epsilon, \ \forall F\in\mathcal{B}_{p}(F_{0}, \epsilon)$$ where $F_{0}$ is a nominal distribution and $\mathcal{B}_{p}(F_{0}, \epsilon)$ is a ball of probability distributions centered at $F_{0}$ which are $\epsilon$-close to the center in the type-$p$ Wasserstein distance and $1\leq k\leq p$.
Any hint would be appreciated to understand how to get this result.

Is there any relationship between $p$ and $k$? In particular is it assumed that $1 \leq k \leq p$?

@MattWerenski yes exactly. I added it in the question

Fix $k \leq p$. Let $X \sim F$ and $X_0 \sim F_0$ and assume that $(X,X_0)$ is jointly distributed according to coupling $\pi$ with respect to the $p$-Wasserstein distance. Then
\begin{align}
    (\mathbb{E}_F[\|X\|^k])^{1/k} &= (\mathbb{E}_{\pi}[\|(X - X_0) + X_0\|^k])^{1/k} \\
    &\leq (\mathbb{E}_{\pi}[\|X - X_0\|^k])^{1/k} + (\mathbb{E}_{F_0}[\|X_0\|^k])^{1/k} & (\text{Minkowski's Ineq}) \\
    &\leq (\mathbb{E}_{\pi}[\|X - X_0\|^p])^{1/p} + (\mathbb{E}_{F_0}[\|X_0\|^k])^{1/k} & (k \leq p, \text{see below}) \\
    &= W_p(F,F_0) + (\mathbb{E}_{F_0}[\|X_0\|^k])^{1/k} & (\pi \text{ opt. coupling}) \\
    &\leq \epsilon + (\mathbb{E}_{F_0}[\|X_0\|^k])^{1/k} & (F \in B_p(F_0,\epsilon))
\end{align}
The step that needs justification is that
$$(\mathbb{E}_{\pi}[\|X - X_0\|^k])^{1/k} \leq (\mathbb{E}_{\pi}[\|X - X_0\|^p])^{1/p}.$$
Since $1 \leq k \leq p$ this is a special case of Hölder's inequality.
